# What session provider types exist for SQLServer?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, session, web-config

If you wanted to implement an SQL session in your web.config, you'd usually have something simple like:

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="myConnectionString"/>
```

But if you want to have a custom provider in order to do something like obscure the connection string with a configuration builder, you could write the following:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="SQLSessionProvider">
   <providers>
      <add name="SQLSessionProvider" connectionStringName="SQLSessionService" type=""/>
   </providers>
</sessionState>

<connectionStrings configBuilders="CS_Environment">
   <add name="SQLSessionService" connectionString="Environment_Key_Here" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The problem is that I don't know what type exists for `mode=SQLServer`. In my searching, I've seen examples for an OBDC session where `type=ObdcSessionStateStore` as well as various other session providers but none for SQLServer.

What session provider types exist for SQLServer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `type` you can use for this, and install via Nuget Package Manager, is

**Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SqlSessionStateProviderAsync**

which should also install **SessionState.SessionStateModule**. If you're installing this to your project for the first time, it'll create a `<sessionState>` template for you in your `web.config`. An example of how to use this is below:

```
<connectionStrings configBuilders="CS_Environment">
   <add name="SQLSession_Connection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="SQLSessionProvider-configBuilder_failed" />
</connectionStrings>

<sessionState cookieless="false" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" mode="Custom" customProvider="SqlSessionStateProviderAsync">
   <providers>
      <add name="SqlSessionStateProviderAsync" connectionStringName="SQLSession_Connection" type="Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SqlSessionStateProviderAsync, Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SqlSessionStateProviderAsync, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
   </providers>
</sessionState>
```